# How to plot data from file from specific lines start at line with some special string

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to execute command similar to

```
plot "data.asc" every ::Q::Q+1500 using 2 with lines
```

But i have problem with that "Q" number. Its not a well known value but number of line with some specific string. Lets say i have line with string "SET_10:" and then i have my data to plot after this specific line. Is there some way how to identify the number of that line with specific string?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to pass the data through GNU `sed` to print just the wanted lines:

```
plot "< sed -n <data.asc '/^SET_10:/,+1500{/^SET_10:/d;p}'" using 1:2 with lines
```

The `-n` stops any output, the *a,b* says between which lines to do the `{...}` commands, and those commands say to delete the trigger line, and `p` print the others.

---

To make sure you have a compatible GNU `sed` try the command on its own, for a short number of lines, eg 5:

```
sed -n <data.asc '/^SET_10:/,+5{/^SET_10:/d;p}'
```

If this does not output the first 5 lines of your data, an alternative is to use `awk`, as it is too difficult in `sed` to count lines without this GNU-specific syntax.  Test the (standard POSIX, not GNU-specific) awk equivalent:

```
awk <data.asc 'end!=0 && NR<=end{print} /^start/{end=NR+5}'
```

and if that is ok, use it in gnuplot as

```
plot "< awk <data.asc 'end!=0 && NR<=end{print} /^start/{end=NR+1500}'" using 1:2 with lines
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, this command does not work for me. With an error "x range is invalid". Its also hard to read what you say. What is your mentioned a and b? I did not see any used in your line.

Comment: You don't say what OS you are using, so I am assuming a version of Unix. I updated my answer with an alternative. The *a,b* was just a quick way of referring to the `/^SET_10:/,+1500` part of the sed command. You are right, this was not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version entirely within gnuplot, with no external commands needed. I tested this on `gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3` using the following `bash` commands to create a simple dataset of 20 lines of which only 5 lines are to be printed from the line with "start" in column 1. You don't need to do this.

```
for i in $(seq 1 20)
do   let j=i%2
     echo "$i $j" 
done >data.asc
sed -i data.asc -e '5a\
start'
```

The actual gnuplot uses a variable `endlno` initially set to NaN (not-a-number) and a function `f` which takes 3 parameters: a boolean `start` saying if column 1 has the matching string, `lno` the current linenumber, and the current column 1 value `val`. If the linenumber is less-than-or-equal-to the ending line number (and therefore it is not still NaN), `f` returns `val`, else if the start condition is true the wanted ending line number is set in variable `endlno` and NaN is returned. If we have not yet seen the start, NaN is returned.

```
gnuplot -persist <<\!
endlno=NaN
f(start,lno,val) = ((lno<=endlno)?val:(start? (endlno=lno+5,NaN) : NaN))
plot "data.asc" using (f(stringcolumn(1)eq "start", $0, $1)):2 with lines 
!
```

Since gnuplot does not plot points with NaN values, we ignore lines upto the start, and again after the wanted number of lines.
In your case you need to change 5 to 1500 and "start" to "SET_10:".